# Multiple inheritance with one base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

(Removed original text as it is unrelated to the current question which has already been answered. See revisions.)

Here is my example `test.hpp` (simplified):

```
class House {
    private:
        int nWindows;
    public:
        House(int nWindows);
        int getNumberOfWindows();
};

class PaintedHouse : public virtual House {
    private:
        int colorCode;
    public:
        PaintedHouse(int nWindows, int colorCode);
        int getColorCode();
};

class OccupiedHouse : public virtual House {
    private:
        int nPeople;
    public:
        OccupiedHouse(int nWindows, int nPeople);
        int getNumberOfPeople();
};

class PaintedOccupiedHouse : public PaintedHouse, OccupiedHouse {
    public:
        PaintedOccupiedHouse(int nWindows, int colorCode, int nPeople);
};
```

And `test.cpp`:

```
#include "test.hpp"

House::House(int nWindows) { this->nWindows = nWindows; }
int House::getNumberOfWindows() { return this->nWindows; }

PaintedHouse::PaintedHouse(int nWindows, int colorCode) : House(nWindows) {
    this->colorCode = colorCode;
}
int PaintedHouse::getColorCode() { return this->colorCode; }

OccupiedHouse::OccupiedHouse(int nWindows, int nPeople) : House(nWindows) {
    this->nPeople = nPeople;
}
int OccupiedHouse::getNumberOfPeople() { return this->nPeople; }

PaintedOccupiedHouse::PaintedOccupiedHouse(int nWindows, int colorCode, int nPeople)
            : PaintedHouse(nWindows, colorCode), OccupiedHouse(nWindows, nPeople) {}
```

GCC returns:

```
test.cpp: In constructor ‘PaintedOccupiedHouse::PaintedOccupiedHouse(int, int, int)’:
test.cpp:18:72: error: no matching function for call to ‘House::House()’
    : PaintedHouse(nWindows, colorCode), OccupiedHouse(nWindows, nPeople) {}
                                                                        ^
test.cpp:18:72: note: candidates are:
test.cpp:4:1: note: House::House(int)
 House::House(int nWindows) { this->nWindows = nWindows; }
 ^
test.cpp:4:1: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
In file included from test.cpp:2:0:
test.hpp:2:7: note: constexpr House::House(const House&)
 class House {
       ^
test.hpp:2:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
test.hpp:2:7: note: constexpr House::House(House&&)
test.hpp:2:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Could you give me any advice what I am doing wrong? Is the general concept correct?

Comment: If this is for recreational purposes OK. But I strongly recommend to avoid such schemes of inheritance for various reasons.

Comment: It seems to me your prof wanted you to explore the virtual base class issues - the names given are very suggestive of the kind of diamond you have drawn.

Comment: @Elemental I don't have experience with virtual base classes... All my attempts to compile it using those failed :(

Comment: @justlerning, perhaps posting your code that fails to compile, with the relevant compiler errors will be useful.

Comment: @justlerning seems it was a useful assignment then. It certainly is possible that way. (and although this diamond CAN be a problem in c++ many large code bases use this sort of structure)

Comment: @RSahu I added a code sample. Could you have a look at it?

Comment: The diamond can be programmed without virtual inheritance, the issues occur when you try to use the diamond in a polymorphic context. E.g. casting from a `PaintedOccupiedHouse` object to a `House*` will be ambiguous when not using virtual inheritance, since there are two paths to do this conversion.

Comment: @dyp As I have to use a "polymorphic context", is there an alternative to virtual inheritance?

Comment: @justlerning Hoes does that context look like? Can you give some usage examples?

Comment: @dyp For example, I have a `vector<House*> houses` and each `House` has additional properties and virtual methods which are overriden in the subclasses, e.g. a painted house returns a different description (but includes the description of the `House` class).

Comment: For a non-virtual diamond between those types, you can use explicit casts: `PaintedOccupiedHouse poh; House* h0 = static_cast<PaintedHouse*>(poh); House* h1 = static_cast<OccupiedHouse*>(poh);` (but of course the behaviour will be different for virtual inheritance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
PaintedOccupiedHouse::PaintedOccupiedHouse(int nWindows, int colorCode, int nPeople)
            : PaintedHouse(nWindows, colorCode), OccupiedHouse(nWindows, nPeople) {}
```

by

```
PaintedOccupiedHouse::PaintedOccupiedHouse(int nWindows, int colorCode, int nPeople)
            : House(nWindows), PaintedHouse(nWindows, colorCode), OccupiedHouse(nWindows, nPeople) {}
```

When you have virtual inheritance, there is only one instance of the `virtual` base class. It must be initialized in the constructor of the most derived class being constructed.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest separating the `Painting` and `Occupied` stuff into separate classes.
Thus you could have:

```
Painted    House   Occupied
   |         |        | 
   +---------+--------+  
             |  
  Painted_Occupied_House
```

Prefer not to set up the *dreaded diamond inheritance*.  See if you can refactor to alleviate the issue.

The diamond interface brings up the possibility of injecting more defects.

Comment: Coming from a JAVA background, I'd like to agree with you (although every JAVA developer obviously hates multiple inheritance). However, the class names (and their implied features) are fixed so I cannot refactor anything. Thanks for your suggestion, anyway!